# Remapping a key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, remapping

I wanted to remap a "menu" key to Left Alt to use it with combinations with other keys. Like Alt+P for example. I used KeyTweak, ShaprKeys and PowerToys but they are not working like i expected them to. Using an online website to check what button and when is pressed I discovered that my remap was triggered only when I released "menu" key. Alt was not registered as being pressed until I let go of "menu" key. Is there any way to remap a key in a way that both press and release are registered so my computer can correctly read combinations with other keys?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To specify I want the remap to be exact. Under this link [link](https://en.key-test.ru) you can see which button is pressed. When I press Left Control the button on screen changes color to white becouse it's pressed. When I use my remapped key the background color changes only for a brief moment when I release the key. I want it to behave exactly like I'm pressing a key, not only when I'm releasing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

The following script will remap the left Windows key to Alt:

```
*LWin::send, {Alt down}
*LWin up::send, {Alt up}
```

If you would like to rather use the right Windows key, substitute
`LWin` with `RWin`

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)
- [Hotkeys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm)

Comment: Thank you for answer. I wanted to use AppsKey but it turns out that is a problem with my keyboard. It doubles up as a function key and becouse of it press down is not registered even without rebinding a key.